# Haskell Text substring occurrences

Tags: string, haskell

I want to find all occurrences(indices) of a substring in a given string.
My strings are of Data.Text.Text type. I was not able to find any function to do this directly. Is there a reason to not provide it? I am aware of the following options -

1. I could use the brute force O(n^2) approach
2. Regular Expressions
3. Write my own Knuth Morris Pratt or Boyer-Moore
   algorithm .

The documentation for [Bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.1/docs/src/Data-ByteString.html#findSubstrings) shows that findSubstrings is deprecated. More than that, the implementation seems to be the naive pattern matching which gives O(n^2) asymptotic performance.

This confuses me. Are we saying that Haskell doesn't have efficient string processing algorithms by default?

Comment: Did you look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/KMP-0.1.0.2/docs/Data-Algorithms-KMP.html ? Also you can use list comprehension to do what you need.

Comment: @Sigrlami I did just now after you suggested. It seems to work on lists. I am trying to use Data.Text.Text. I don't think it will work on that unless I unpack the Text to String.

Comment: @Sigrlami also, are you suggesting the O(nm) approach using list comprehensions ? I am aware of that but it would be inefficient for large text.

Comment: added answer with Data.Text

Answer (score 1):

You can use [breakOnAll](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.0.4/docs/Data-Text.html#v:breakOnAll) which have O(n+m) asymptotic performance.

```
module Main where

import Data.Text as T(map, length, pack, breakOnAll)

main = do
  print $ subStrs "Grey Hound dig down" "ou"
  print $ subStrInd "Grey Hound dig down" "ou"
  print $ subStrs "abababababaaabbaba" "ab"
  print $ subStrInd "abababababaaabbaba" "ab"

-- Return list of non-overlapping occurrences of sub in str
subStrs str sub = breakOnAll (pack sub) (pack str)

-- Return the indices of occurrences
subStrInd str sub =  Prelude.map (\x -> T.length $ fst x) $ subStrs str sub
```

In bad cases, this function's time complexity degrades towards O(n*m).

Also, you have needed algorithms already implemented, look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/KMP-0.1.0.2/docs/Data-Algorithms-KMP.html

Comment: I want to find the indices of overlapping occurrences too. Also KMP implementation seems to be designed for Lists, not for Text. I will have to unpack text to use it.

Comment: Have I misunderstood your comment? 
type String = [Char], so Strings are lists too.

Comment: @AviralGoel Uhm... the `breakOnAll` function seems to work on `Text`. For the index, you can use the length of the first pair component (`length` is O(1) on `Text`).

Comment: @matcheek String is list of chars, it just `type String = [Char]` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.1.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#t%3AString

Comment: @chi It does not provide overlapping occurrences.

Comment: @matcheek  I am using `Data.Text.Text` not `String`. KMP is designed for `List` or `String` but not for `Text` type.

Comment: @AviralGoel You're right (and length is NOT even O(1) on `Text` as I expected!) :-(